# If $(x+1)^6=x^6$ then prove that $x=\frac{-1}2-i\cot (\frac{\theta}2)$ where $\theta=\frac{2k\pi}6$, $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, solution-verification

**QUESTION**
If $(x+1)^6=x^6$ then prove that $x=\Large{\frac{-1}2}$$-i\cot (\large\frac\theta2)$ where $\theta=\Large\frac{2k\pi}6$, $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$

---

How can we prove this question using complex numbers. We need to prove it using roots of complex numbers.

If we consider$$\frac{(x+1)^{6}}{x^{6}} = 1$$
then $$\frac{(x+1)}{x}=(1)^\frac{1}{6} = \cos (\theta)^\frac{1}{6} + i \sin (\theta)^\frac{1}{6}$$

On further simplification I get the answer$$x=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{i\cot(\theta/2)}{2}$$

But we need to prove $x=\frac{-1}{2}
-i\cot (\theta/2)$. What can be the error?

My solved example is here
[image]

Comment: Please refer to this:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. I have made the edits for you now, please ensure that in the future you use MathJax to type your question. Also please refrain from putting images in the question as images are sometimes hard to understand and lead to downvotes.

Comment: ok ...thank you

Answer (score 3):

First note that $k = 0$ does not give a solution, as $cot(0)$ is undefined. This should match with the intuition that your equation
$$(x+1)^6 = x^6 \Longrightarrow 6x^5 + 15x^4 + 20x^3 + 15x^2 + 6x + 1 = 0$$
should only have up to 5 roots by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Otherwise, your solution is sound. You can verify that the roots are
$$x_1 = -\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} \cot(\frac{\pi}{6}),$$
$$x_2 = -\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} \cot(\frac{2\pi}{6}),$$
$$x_3 = -\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} \cot(\frac{3\pi}{6}),$$
$$x_4 = -\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} \cot(\frac{4\pi}{6}),$$
$$x_5 = -\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} \cot(\frac{5\pi}{6}).$$

Comment: Thank you so much